# Orientation in list css

Tags: html, css

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```

this show me:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

How can i make:

aaa bbb ccc

what i must add for css?

Comment: you need to change defaut display of li for one that is alike inlin-block-level-elements. floatting will do it (most common way used, but not the most efficient in some cases)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use float, no no. Use `inline-block`

HTML:

```
 <ul id="list">
        <li>aaa</li>
        <li>bbb</li>
        <li>ccc</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#eee;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-right:-4px;
    padding:10px;
    border-right:1px solid white;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QPuTs/1/

If IE7 (put this in your `<head>` tags)

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>
ul li {
display:inline;
zoom:1;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Or alternatively in your external CSS like so:

```
ul li { display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline; }
```

Comment: @SonasishRoy Fixed. A lot better than `float:left;`

Comment: Both solutions work here so could you explain why one shouldn't use float here?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `display:inline`

```
#list li {
   display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btBdW/

Answer (score 3):

Mention `float:left` in `li`

```
#list li{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
}
```

[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/gnabB/)

Comment: `inline-block` **not** float

Comment: Testing your code indicates that `padding-right:10px;` is needed too.  Otherwise you get "aaabbbccc".

Comment: @adaam Both achieve the same effect here

Comment: @FelipeAls The same "effect" yes, but one is the right way to do it and the other is not.

Comment: @adaam According to? I don't see what's more *right* here or more *wrong* there

Comment: @FelipeAls Floats remove the element from the document flow, whilst inline-block does not, which is a far superior solution. This means there is no need for clearfix when the page becomes more complicated. Inline blocks align vertically at the baseline whilst floats vertically align at the top. There are more reasons that I can't be bothered to list. IMO it's like using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @adaam if you check inline-block with some background color in li, you will find some unwanted space between li. why this is coming and how to remove this space?

Comment: @SonasishRoy There is a whitespace problem with inline-block that has been reported which is the problem you're describing. Various solutions available here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<style>
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;   
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 2px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#list {
list-style:none;
}

#list li {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

aaa

bbb

ccc

this show me:

aaa
bbb
ccc

so you want to display as horizontal menu? yes

then see code here

in css

```
#list{
width:900px;
height:30px;
background-color:green;
}
#list ul{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
list-style-type:none;
}
#list ul li{
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;
}
#list ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:12px;
padding:10px 5px;
}
```